# Emit angular2 event from a typescript class that is **not** an angular component

Tags: angular, events, typescript, event-handling

I am building an interactive web app, and the core part of my webpage is an angular component, `interactionStage.component`, which houses a typescript class `InteractionStage.ts`. The latter, as it's name implies, is a graphical "stage" which users can interact with, it listens for and responds to a number of mouse events which are important in the context of the stage.

Omitting unnecessary details, my `interactionStage.component` looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'interaction-stage',
    templateUrl: './interactionStage.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./interactionStage.component.css'],
})
export class InteractionStage.component implements OnInit {
    private stage : InteractionStage;

    constructor(){
        this.stage = new InteractionStage();
    }

    catchImportantEvent($event) {
        console.log($event);
        //Do stuff with the event data
    }
}
```

There's not much to show, but just to give you some context, my `InteractionStage` class looks like this:

```
export class InteractionStage {

    constructor(){
        //initialize important stuff here
    }

    public emitImportantEvent() {
        //TODO: emit an event so that interactionStage.component receives it
    }
}
```

Given the nature of `InteractionStage`, it needs to be able to emit events when an action happens on it, for example to notify a user of something, display a modal, or to alter the DOM. These events need to be received by `InteractionStage.component`, and in the future, might need to be received by other angular components on the page.

The problem I'm facing is is emitting these events from `InteractionStage`. I know how to emit and catch events using angular components, by using the `@Output` notation. As a stab in the dark, I tried using that in my `InteractionStage` class:

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class InteractionStage {

    @Output importantEvent: EventEmitter<any> new EventEmitter();

    constructor(){
        //initialize important stuff here
    }

    public emitImportantEvent() {
        var importantData = "here is a very important string";
        this.importantEvent.emit(importantData);
    }
}
```

Then I tried to catch this event in my `InteractionStage.component` like this:

```
 <interaction-stage (importantEvent)=catchImportantEvent($event)></interaction-stage>
```

But, absolutely nothing happens. No event is received and nothing is logged to the console.

**Am I doing something wrong, or is what I'm trying to do impossible? If it can't be done, how else can I send an event from a typescript file and have it caught by an angular component?**

I realise I can pass a reference of `InteractionStage.component` into the constructor of `InteractionStage`, but I think that's a code smell - coupling that is unneccesary. The interaction stage should not know about the angular component that holds it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Component({
selector: 'interaction-stage',
    templateUrl: './interactionStage.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./interactionStage.component.css'],
})
export class InteractionStageComponent implements OnInit {
    private stage : InteractionStage;
    @Output myEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor(){
        this.stage = new InteractionStage(myEmitter);
    }

    catchImportantEvent($event) {
        console.log($event);
        //Do stuff with the event data
    }
}

export class InteractionStage {

    constructor(private myEmitter: EventEmitter<any>){
        //initialize important stuff here
    }

    public emitImportantEvent() {
      this.myEmitter.emit("my data");
        //TODO: emit an event so that interactionStage.component receives it
    }
}
```

I also changed InteractionStage.component to InteractionStageComponent because the angularCLI generates it like that so I assume its a practice